# NSTimer days countdown and sending to label

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, countdown

I have a button to trigger NSTimer to countdown 3 days. How do I get a label showing 2 days left or 0 days left in the tableviewCell. and also I want to color the cell with red color when 0 days left. And in the cell there is a button to reset the timer for another 3 days. Objective-c. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store the timer expired Day in the User Defaults. This you may do this in an IBAction method to set the new Expiring Date. Running this action again resets the value.

```
   NSInteger expiredInDays = 3;

// Calculate the Date.
// Get the Date
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval  tiNow = [now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
tiNow = tiNow + 60*60*24*expiredInDays;
NSDate * expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:tiNow];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:expires forKey:@"Expired Date"];
```

Ask for the expiring Day where you need it in your code.

```
NSDate *expiredDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Expired Date"];
NSLog(@"Expires in: %@",expiredDate);
```

Comment: Don't use `NSUserDefaults` as a global variable. Some days are 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: Thx a lot @voltae ! It works with some modifications below. Before it showed me just date in future when it should be expired, but I want to see a countdown for only days.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was like this:

```
    - (IBAction)In3DaysButton:(id)sender
    {
    NSInteger expiredInDays = 4;

    // Calculate the Date.
    // Get the Date

    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval  tiNow = [now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    tiNow = tiNow + 60*60*24*expiredInDays;
    NSDate * expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:tiNow];

   NSDateComponents *countdown = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                               components:(NSCalendarUnitDay)
                                          // | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond)
                               fromDate:[NSDate date]
                               toDate:expires
                               options:0];

    NSString *myDays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[countdown day]];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDays forKey:@"Expired_Date"];
```

}

Then when I want get it:

```
    NSDate *expiredDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Expired_Date"];
    doItLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" f_ck me in %@ day(s)",   expiredDate];

    //And for coloring label I add after

    if ([NSDate date] > expiredDate) doItLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```